# Android Studio does not compile when using deprecated API

Tags: android, intellij-idea, gradle, deprecated, android-studio

I am having issues compiling and running my application on Android Studio.

**The problem:** It doesn't like that I am using deprecated APIs. (from `gradlew compileDebug --stacktrace`. [Full stacktrace here](http://pastebin.com/Z7ykqUVf)

```
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
```

**The Background:**

- I am using a PreferenceActivity which uses `onPreferenceTreeClick` and `addPreferencesFromResource(int)`, both deprecated methods.
- I am using ABS and ViewPager libraries, which both seem to also be using deprecated methods in their code.

**The Question:**

- Can the run configurations be edited to an extend where It can compile succesfully **despite** of the deprecated APIs?
- What can be changed/edited/modified to allow the build to compile succesfully?

Given that I plan on supporting pre-ICS devices and the usage of deprecated APIS shoudln't suppose a problem.

**EDIT**

So, the compiler from command prompt indicates the build was succesful, problem is running from Android Studio directly, the build process fails:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

The problem seems to be something I have no idea how to fix, the popular line is:

```
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added:
```

which is happening at three different places:

```
Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoStubImpl;
Landroid/support/v4/app/ActivityCompatHoneycomb;
Landroid/support/v4/app/LoaderManager;
```

Here's some more info: [Full Compiler output in Android Studio](http://pastebin.com/R60SMqrm)

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':LaPrensa:dexDebug'.
> Running C:\Users\SkullKandy\AppData\Local\Android\android-studio\sdk\build-tools\android-4.2.2\dx.bat failed.
```

Comment: At least with Ant, those are warning messages, not indications of a failed build. Moreover, your build succeeded, according to the trace you have.

Comment: Correct, building with Ant on Eclipse works like a charm, trying it in Android studio/gradle seems to be the problem.

Comment: Since your trace says that it compiled successfully, what is your evidence of a problem?

Comment: Check the added details please.

Comment: You appear to be pulling in two (or more) separate copies of the Android Support JAR. Since ActionBarSherlock already has one, you should be able to get rid of your own copy of that JAR. That being said, my advice is for Ant and Eclipse, and I do not know if there is another preferred resolution for Android Studio.

Comment: @CommonsWare i have this error too. And i can not handle it. It took my 2 days. Can you guys please check my question ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19956564/gradle-execution-failed-for-task-myappdexdebug-could-not-call-incrementa

Answer (score 0):

You have simply to add this code to `build.gradle` (in android section)

```
lintOptions {
    abortOnError false
}
```

Comment: If you use this gradle won't show you errors anymore, that's not very useful!

Comment: @stef With abortOnError false Gradle still shows the errors the difference that doesn't abort the build because of them.

Comment: True, I should have said "you won't get notified when error occurs", my bad