# Build Failed : Gradle with uiautomator android

Tags: android, automation, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-uiautomator

I had been trying to build my test project jar file using gradle instead of ant with uiautomator android but I am getting BUILD FAILED error.

[image]

I had referred using gradle with uiautomator android form here - http://wiliamsouza.github.io/#/2013/10/30/android-uiautomator-gradle-build-system

I had used the following commands :

```
 android create uitest-project -n ProjectName -t 46 -p  D:\Android_Workspace\Smriti\ProjectName 

 set ANDROID_HOME=D:\Android Development\android-sdk

 cd D:\Android_Workspace\Smriti\ProjectName

 gradle build   //here I get build failed error
```

My gradle-properties is as shown below :

```
androidSdkHome = D:/Android Development/android-sdk
androidSdkTarget = android-19
androidSdkBuildToolsDir = build-tools/19.0.0
```

and build.gradle is -

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'

sourceCompatibility = 1.5
targetCompatibility = 1.5

version = '0.1'

project.ext {
   dexDir = new File('build/dex')
   distDir = new File('./dist')
}

repositories {
   mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
   compile fileTree(dir: androidSdkHome + '/platforms/' + androidSdkTarget, include:  '*.jar')
   compile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
}

jar {
   doLast {
     tasks.dex.execute()
   }
}

task dex(dependsOn: jar, type:Exec) {
   println 'Building dex...'
   project.dexDir.mkdirs()
   workingDir '.'
   commandLine androidSdkHome + '/' + androidSdkBuildToolsDir + '/' + 'dx', '--dex', '--  no-strict', '--output=' + buildDir +'/dex/' + project.name + '.jar', jar.archivePath
   doLast {
      tasks.dist.execute()
   }
}

task dist(dependsOn:dex, type:Copy) {
   project.distDir.mkdirs()
   from(project.dexDir)
   into(project.distDir)
   include('*.jar')
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: are you still having this issue?

Answer (score 0):

It might be because the sdk folder name containing a space. Change the Android sdk folder from **D:\Android Development** to any other folder with no space in them,or rename the folder to **Android_Development**

Comment: I renamed folder to Android_Development and I am still getting the same error. Anything else I should do to fix this?

Comment: You renamed it alright,but did you changed the path in the ANDROID_HOME variable?

Comment: Yes I did. I changed it in ANDROID_HOME variable and also in my gradle.properties file.

Comment: yeah . Same screenshot which I had posted above with change in path as  Android_Developemnt

Comment: try adding compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:+' in the dependency block of build.gradle

Comment: android-support-v4.jar lies inside Android Private Libraries in my test project -  D:\Android_Workspace\Smriti\ProjectName\libs\android-support-v4.jar. Can you help me with the exact syntax to add this inside build.gradle file?  Should it be something like                compile 'com.android.support:support-v4.jar'

Comment: i think so,refer this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19956564/gradle-execution-failed-for-task-myappdexdebug-could-not-call-incrementa

Comment: I added compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:+' as given in that link but didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this issue on windows PC.
I have a custom Gradle task to create dex files and I was running it with commandLine command. The issue was it cannot identify dx tool in android SDK home.
So I have changed the path in commandLine to include `.bat` at the end of dx tool in my build.gradle file.

`commandLine androidSdkHome + '/' + androidSdkBuildToolsDir + '/' + 'dx.bat', '--dex', '--no-strict', '--output=' + buildDir +'\\' + project.name + '.jar', jar.archivePath`